# How do I clear a drawn line in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a simple test program that draws an axis/crosshair in a form.  I have two text boxes, where I put in the x-center and y-center and draw the crosshair based on that.  I want to be able to put in new coordinates, and move the crosshair to the new position, but when I do, the old drawing stays there.  I want to erase the old drawing and then draw the new one.

My code is below:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mypen As Pen
        mypen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Red, 1)
        Dim mygraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
        Dim x_center = Integer.Parse(xPos.Text)
        Dim y_center = Integer.Parse(yPos.Text)
        mygraphics.DrawLine(mypen, x_center - 50, x_center, x_center + 50, x_center)
        mygraphics.DrawLine(mypen, y_center, y_center - 50, y_center, y_center + 50)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should do all drawing in the paint event.  CreateGraphics is never the right way.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The Drawing on a Control surface is usually handled through the Control's [Paint()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event, using its [PaintEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) class object.

To raise the Paint() event of a Control, call its [Invalidate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
(*Note that the `Invalidate()` method has a number of overloads, some of which allows to re-paint only a defined region of the surface.*)

If a Graphics object is created elsewhere (as you're doing now), the drawings performed with this object will persist or will be erased when you don't want to (e.g. if a Control needs to repaint itself - and this happens quite often - the drawings will be erased).
Also, the Graphics object can't be stored. It will become an invalid object as soon as a Control has repainted its surface.

You could re-design you code in this way.

- Create a shared Pen (you can redefined it at any moment if you need to, using its properties) so you don't have to create a new one every time you need to draw something.
- Use a shared Point field to store the current center of the drawing.
- Move the `Graphics.DrawLine()` to the Paint event of your Form.
- *Remember to **`Dispose()`** **the Pen object** when the Form closes (you can use it's Dispose() pre-defined method).*

```
Public Class Form1

    Private mypen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
    Private Position As Point = New Point(-1, -1)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (Integer.TryParse(xPos.Text, Position.X) = True) AndAlso
           (Integer.TryParse(yPos.Text, Position.Y) = True) Then
            Me.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        If Position.X > -1 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, Position.X - 50, Position.Y, Position.X + 50, Position.Y)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, Position.X, Position.Y - 50, Position.X, Position.Y + 50)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is, however, not that much efficient, because you need to invalidate the entire Form.

For a full implementation, take a look a this Class [(PasteBin - CrossHair)](https://pastebin.com/J0nef4DV).